# Name of a book or series with lightsaber like weapons but they pierce the skin and use blood for something

Tags: story-identification

There was a battle where a person's bodyguards get their charge out on a spaceship, maybe as a baby. The person was probably from a royal family. I read it somewhere in the '99-'03 time frame; I got it out of my high school library.

It involved lightsaber-like weapons that pierce the skin and use blood for something.

Comment: Sounds like Soulbones, from a short story in Space Eldritch II: The Haunted Stars, which I totally recommend BTW.

Comment: It was definitely an actual novel. Thanks though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the "Star of the Guardians" series by Weis & Hickman.

Comment: Can you explain why you think this is the right book?

Comment: I think that might be it, thanks!

Comment: To expand, based on my own recollection of the books as well as a quick check of Wikipedia and TVTropes, we have (1) The royal family was almost entirely wiped out, and the story includes some plot around getting one of the remaining members to reclaim his birthright, and (2) swords that are essentially lightsabres except that they inject you with nanomachines and if you're not one of the royal family you'll die soon after using them as a result.